# Azure Eclipse : cspack.exe: Error : The specified path, file name, or both are too long

Tags: eclipse, azure

When I try to deploy an application with eclipse on tomcat in local, I have this error:

> [windowsazurepackage] cspack.exe: Error   : The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.

I have already change the environment variable `_CSRUN_STATE_DIRECTORY`.

But I haven't this error when I don't choose the JDK and my Tomcat when I create he Azure Project deployment. But in this case, my application doesn't start.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this by editing `package.xml` in the deployment project root and changing the destination folder by searching for the following line:

```
<!-- This is the directory where the Windows Azure deployment package or folder will be saved --> 
<property location="${basedir}\deploy" name="wapackagedir"/>
```

...and then changing `${basedir}` to a shorter and absolute path like `c:\publish`