# Path too long error when trying to run Java/Eclipse app on azure emulator

Tags: java, eclipse, azure

I have a Java web application which I try to deploy on Azure, using Eclipse and the Azure SDK and Eclipse plugin. Now when I try to run the application in the Azure emulator. I get the following dreaded error:

```
[windowsazurepackage] cspack.exe: Error : The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.
```

I'm using Glassfish 3 and the Java 1.7 JDK. I have tried subst-ing the folder, so it's as short as possible. But nothing seems to help. It looks like the Glassfish or Java SDK result in too deep folders. I'm surprised In 2013 MS still hasn't solved this!

The following question seems to be the same. But the given answer is not helping, and I don't know how to give the original question renewed attention.

[Azure Eclipse : cspack.exe: Error : The specified path, file name, or both are too long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13933705/azure-eclipse-cspack-exe-error-the-specified-path-file-name-or-both-are-t)

As a reaction on the comment of Martin Sawicki, this is the log. And as you can see the path I'm using is very short. I even tried to subst, and use another drive for the projects, but then the plugin bombs with a nullpointer exception.

```
Buildfile: C:\A\azr\package.xml

checkResetScript:

resetEmulator:

createwapackage:
    [move] Warning: Could not find file C:\A\azr\dy to copy.
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\A\azr\dy
[windowsazurepackage] Verified attributes.
[windowsazurepackage] Role "wrol1": Verifying the approot "C:\A\azr\wrol1\approot"
[windowsazurepackage] Role "wrol1": Importing components...
[windowsazurepackage]   Imported as 'jdk1.7.0_17' from "C:\Program             Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17"
[windowsazurepackage]   Imported as 'glassfishv3' from "C:\Glassfish3\glassfishv3"
[windowsazurepackage]   Imported as 'OW-MobileClient-QNH.war' from "C:\A\azr\..\OW-MobileClient-QNH"
[windowsazurepackage] Role "wrol1": Finished importing components
[windowsazurepackage] Role "wrol1": Generating component deployment script...
[windowsazurepackage] Role "wrol1": Created internal startup script
[windowsazurepackage] Starting package generation...
[windowsazurepackage] Executing '"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Azure\.NET SDK\2012-10\bin\cspack.exe" "C:\A\azr\ServiceDefinition.csdef" /role:wrol1;"C:\A\azr\wrol1\approot" /out:"C:\A\azr\dy\WindowsAzurePackage.cspkg"'...
[windowsazurepackage] Process started
[windowsazurepackage] Windows(R) Azure(TM) Packaging Tool version 1.8.0.0
[windowsazurepackage] for Microsoft(R) .NET Framework 3.5
[windowsazurepackage] Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
[windowsazurepackage] C:\A\azr\ServiceDefinition.csdef: Warning  CloudServices040 : The 'schemaVersion' attribute is unspecified. Please set the attribute to avoid this warning.
[windowsazurepackage] cspack.exe: Error   : The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.
[windowsazurepackage] Waiting for process to exit..
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, as you suspect,  you're running into that age-old path length limitation in Windows.

Interestingly, if you were to deploy this to the cloud, it might actually work ok, despite not working in the emulator. That's because it the cloud, your approot directory (where your payload gets put by default) is simply e:\approot. But on your local computer, there are probably several directories your Eclipse project is in, and then several more that the Azure SDK creates for your emulator deployment, and then the Glassfish folder structure and file names are pretty deep too, so it's easy to hit a file within it whose effective path is just too long (>260 chars).

Having said that, there are ways to get Glassfish to work in the Windows Azure emulator from the Eclipse plugin - it's something we've been testing and have implemented a number of workarounds for under the hood to minimize the probability of users running into it.

So if you're seeing this issue despite all that, I'm wondering what is different about your Glassfish project from mine, where I'm not having this problem. Here's what I'm doing:

a) I have a Windows Azure deployment project in my Eclipse workspace, and my project's effective path is: c:\abcde\fghi\MyAzureProject  (the length is what matters)

b) When I created this project, in the project wizard, on the Server tab, I selected my unzipped glassfish installation, which is at: C:\abcde\fghijklmopqr\glassfish3. (By doing it this way, I rely on the Eclipse plugin's knowledge of how to install glassfish)

c) Then I just click Run in Emulator, and everything works fine.

If you're doing exactly the same, but your Eclipse's project path is longer than mine (c:\abcde\fghi\MyAzureProject --- 27 chars), then see if saving your Eclipse project under a shorter total path length helps.

Comment: I did a) and b). But that doesn't help me. I guess I'm gonna use an Ubuntu VM to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

It is likely the depth of the folder structure within glassfish\domains\domain(X)... due to apps you have already deployed.

I was running Glassfish Server Open Source Edition 3.0.1 and ran into the same issue. I first thought it was a versioning issue but after downloading a vanilla copy of that same edition I was able to re-package and deploy to the Azure emulator, no problem.